# Deprecated std::is_literal_type in C++17

Tags: c++, std, c++17, deprecated, type-traits

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), the trait [`std::is_literal_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_literal_type) is deprecated in C++17. The question is **why** and **what is the preferred replacement** for the future to check whether a type is a [literal type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[As stated in P0174](http://wg21.link/P0174):

> The `is_literal` type trait offers negligible value to generic code, as what is really needed is the ability to know that a specific construction would produce constant initialization. The core term of a *literal type* having at least one constexpr constructor is too weak to be used meaningfully.

Basically, what it's saying is that there's no code you can guard with `is_literal_type_v` and have that be sufficient to ensure that your code actually is constexpr. This isn't good enough:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_literal_type_v<T>, void> SomeFunc()
{
  constexpr T t{};
}
```

There's no guarantee that this is legal. Even if you guard it with `is_default_constructible<T>` that doesn't mean that it's *constexpr* default constructible.

What you would need is an `is_constexpr_constructible` trait. Which does not as of yet exist.

> However, the (already implemented) trait does no harm, and allows compile-time introspection for which core-language type-categories a given template parameter might satisfy. Until the Core Working Group retire the notion of a literal type, the corresponding library trait should be preserved.
>
> The next step towards removal (after deprecation) would be to write a paper proposing to remove the term from the core language while deprecating/removing the type trait.

So the plan is to eventually get rid of the whole definition of "literal types", replacing it with something more fine-grained.

Comment: Interestingly I thought that `std::is_literal_type` provides a safe check whether a type can be used in constexpr expressions or not. Nevertheless this is a good answer.

Comment: But could you use this for checking the function arguments, e.g as in [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qY9uUeIdGupoGo8R) or would it also break in some cases?

Comment: @berkus: For what purpose? `constexpr` as applied to a template will *always* be conditional. If you instantiate it with a type that makes the function violate the rules of `constexpr`, then it won't be `constexpr`. So what's the point of the "check"? And if `T` doesn't have a `constexpr` `operator+` (which the check doesn't test), then the function won't be `constexpr` either. So what is the point?

Comment: @NicolBolas not sure anymore, this was some discussion about C++ which I already forgot. I guess this was to provide more sensible error messages when constexprness is violated, but current gcc/clang seem to provide reasonably well-versed messages. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: pinging 4 year later, has the replacement been found by WG21?

Comment: @NicolBolas do concepts allow trick with , like

 requires { constexpr bool dummy = Bla{}.Lol()++, false;}

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Actually, I was wrong about the `constexpr` declaration thing in requires expressions. They can only have expressions, not declarations like that.

Comment: This trait was at least useful in helping users identify if the type they are preparing is literal. After all, the term *is* still used in the current (C++20 draft) spec (literal definition on page 69). Perhaps the baby was thrown out with the bathwater.

Comment: @user2023370: "*This trait was at least useful in helping users identify if the type they are preparing is literal.*" But that's a false negative. Just because a type is literal doesn't mean that a particular `constexpr` use of it will work. If some template code expects the type to be `constexpr` usable in some way, *that* is what the user will have to verify. Giving users false confidence isn't useful.