# How to static_assert that type is viable for template non-type parameter in c++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, constexpr

I have a type `TimeDuration`. Right now it is [literal type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) and I can use it as non-type template parameter. Such usage is very far away (compilation-wise) from type definition, so if anybody modifies `TimeDuration` such that it is no loner literal, it will be noticed much later.

So I put `static_assert(std::is_literal_type_v<TimeDuration>);` just after class definition. However, `is_literal_type` is deleted in c++20. What can I replace this with?

I know about [Deprecated std::is_literal_type in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351816/deprecated-stdis-literal-type-in-c17), but the answer basically says that my problem doesn't exist.

Comment: For reference, there was briefly `std::has_strong_structural_equality`, but when class-type NTTPs were rewritten and that term was removed the trait was deliberately [dropped without replacement](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3354), partly because it wouldn’t be clear whether it was supposed to mean “supported in C++20” or “supported in current C++” in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very simple way to get a compile error on whether a type is appropriate for use in a non-type template parameter: use it in a NTTP. The compiler will complain if it's not appropriate.

You can easily write a small template somewhere and instantiate it explicitly with your type. Something like:

```
template<auto val> struct checker{};

template struct checker<MyType(/*insert params for constexpr function here*/)>;
```

`is_literal_type` wouldn't be appropriate anyway (which is why it's going away) because being a literal type isn't nearly as restrictive as C++20's user-defined NTTP rules. Yes, a user-defined NTTP must be a literal type, but it must also have a number of other qualities.

Comment: Great simple idea, thanks!
In case sb else tries this, keep in mind this feature needs gcc-9+ or clang-11+ (or later, clang-10 doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the unicity of the template signature (avoiding std::is_same with classes), you can simply pass a TimeDuration variable (or anything you want) by const reference:

```
template <const auto& TimeDurationRef>
requires std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(TimeDurationRef)>, TimeDuration>
void foo();// or struct Foo {};
```

But you cannot pass on-the-fly temporaries. You need to declare the referenced variable as static constexpr to ensure static storage duration.