# How to classify an NTTP class by creating a type trait?

Tags: c++, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

In C++20, NTTP extends new types which brings us the term *structural*:

- l-value ref
- integral
- pointer, pointer to member, and null pointer
- enumeration
- floating point
- A class in which: all base classes and non-static data members are public and non-mutable and the types of data members and base classes must also be *structural* recursively (I guess) and also the array.

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Here is a work around implementation that won't simply work:

```cpp
template <auto>
struct nttp_test {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_structural : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_structural<T, std::void_t<nttp_test<T{}>>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_structural_v = is_structural<T>::value;
```

I'm not entirely sure if that works but I'm worried about the *default initialization* (I can't also use `std::declval`).

If it's impossible to implement, does it involve *compiler magic*?

Comment: This solves part of your problem, by having a compile time_error if you try to use `is_structural<T>` with a non-structural type `T`: https://godbolt.org/z/Ts9Gzz5aa (it could probably be fixed to be `false`, but I couldn't manage it)

Comment: Reopened since https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929851 assumes that you know how to construct a `T`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <auto>
struct nttp_test {};

template<class T> 
concept structural = requires { []<T x>(nttp_test<x>) { }; };
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/7bh9odj4h)

Comment: Unfortunately current clang trunk (18) rejects as a hard error; a workaround is to use another test template `template<class T, template<T> class> struct nttp_test2;` and test `typename nttp_test2<T, nttp_test>;`: https://godbolt.org/z/zd5Tc4Tnj

Comment: Filed https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/71684

Answer (score 1):

One more C++20 construct could be of help here:

```cpp
template<auto> class Meow {};

template<class T> concept meow = requires { typename Meow<T{}>; };

struct Nyan {};

int main() {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << meow<int> << '\n';
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << meow<Nyan> << '\n';
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << meow<std::string> << '\n';
}
```

To convert a concept into a good old trait, well... `template<class T> using is_meow = std::bool_constant<meow<T>>;`.

Comment: I'm really confused if NTTP also requires default initialization on types.

Comment: @DesmondGold It does not, this does not work