# Is this a correct method of detecting structural types?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, non-type-template-parameter

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855731/how-to-classify-an-nttp-class-by-creating-a-type-trait) proposed the following method to detect types that are valid for non-type template parameters ("structural types"):

```
template <auto>
struct nttp_test {};

template<class T> 
concept structural = requires { []<T x>(nttp_test<x>) { }; };
```

I thought a simpler version of this would suffice:

```
template<class T>
concept structural = requires { []<T>{}; };
```

However, when trying the following test program

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
concept structural = requires { []<T>{}; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << "int: " << structural<int> << '\n';
    std::cout << "int*: " << structural<int*> << '\n';
    std::cout << "int&: " << structural<int&> << '\n';
    std::cout << "int&&: " << structural<int&&> << '\n';
    std::cout << "void: " << structural<void> << '\n';
    std::cout << "void(): " << structural<void()> << '\n';
    std::cout << "void(*)(): " << structural<void(*)()> << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::ostream: " << structural<std::ostream> << '\n';
}
```

in GCC, [the output is](https://godbolt.org/z/KEbeKf8Go)

```
int: 1
int*: 1
int&: 1
int&&: 1
void: 1
void(): 1
void(*)(): 1
std::ostream: 1
```

It appears that, in GCC, every type satisfies the concept. By contrast, clang and MSVC print 0 for `int&&`, `void`, and `std::ostream`. This is also what GCC does if the other, more elaborate method, is used instead.

Is my method correct, or is this a bug in GCC?

Comment: This is clearly a GCC bug since `[]<void>{}` is obviously ill-formed.

Comment: What exactly is the point of detecting whether a type is structural? What are you going to conditionally do based on such a determination? If you need to use a type as an NTTP... then you need to do it, and giving a compile error in the event that the user has provided such a type makes sense.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I created an issue on GCC's bug tracker: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106964.

Comment: @NicolBolas you can use an alternative approach, e.g. constructing a unique closure type, or `bit_cast`ing a trivially copyable `T` to `array<byte>`.

Comment: @ecatmur: But what's the point of the explicit condition? If `T` is not a type that can do constexpr stuff, then your function templated on `T` won't be constexpr for that instantiation. Why not just do it the way that works all the time?

Comment: @NicolBolas using a structural type as an NTTP gives better symbols and diagnostics than the various workarounds.